# Displaying values from two different tables inside dropdownlist using php

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have two database tables, `released_movies` and `upcoming_movies`. I need to display the field `rel_movies` in `release_movies` table and `up_movies` field in `upcoming_movies` table inside a single `dropdown` list. Below is my code.

```
<select name="film" class="form-control">
<?php
include "connection.php";
$sql="select rel_movies from released_movies";
$sqlr=$con->query($sql);
while($row=$sqlr->fetch_assoc())
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['rel_movies'];?>"><?php echo $row['rel_movies'];?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

I have no idea how to display `up_movies` field into it. Is this possible .Thanks in advance.

Comment: display same as where you have done as in first dropdown..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    <?php include "connection.php"; ?>
    <select name="film" class="form-control">
    <?php
        $sqlr="select rel_movies from released_movies";
        $sqlrr=$con->query($sqlr);
        while($row=$sqlrr->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['rel_movies'];?>">
<?php echo $row['rel_movies'];?>
</option>
    <?php }
        $sqlu="select up_movies from upcoming_movies";
        $sqluu=$con->query($sqlu);
        while($rowu=$sqluu->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $rowu['up_movies'];?>">
<?php echo $rowu['up_movies'];?>
</option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use **UNION** in mysql for getting records from more than one table.

In your case you may use **UNION** for getting released as well as upcoming movies, no need of execution of two MySQL query.

```
<select name="film" class="form-control">
<?php
include "connection.php";
$sql="select rel_movies as movies_name from released_movies 
UNION select up_movies as movies_name from upcoming_movies";
$sqlr=$con->query($sql);
while($row=$sqlr->fetch_assoc())
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['movies_name'];?>"><?php echo $row['movies_name'];?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
```

More info about UNION: [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways then one to accomplish this.

If you like to have the upcoming movies first or last in the array you could do something like this. First get your result from the database back in an array, and not in single instances. Only then you can do something with them

```
function fetch_all($result, $resulttype = MYSQLI_ASSOC){
    if (method_exists($result, 'fetch_all')){  // Compatibility layer with PHP < 5.3
        $res = mysqli_fetch_all($result, $resulttype);
    }
    else{
        for ($res = array(); $tmp = $this->fetch_array( $resulttype );) $res[] = $tmp;
    }

    return $res;
}


$sqlr=$con->query($sql);
$relMovieArray = fetch_all($sqlr,'MYSQLI_NUM');

 // for putting the array's one after the other.

for($x = 0; $x < count($upMovieArray); $x++){
    $relMovieArray[count($relMovieArray)] = $upMovieArray[$x];
} 


//Or you could use array_merge. That just pushes two array's into each other.

$movieArray = array_merge($relMovieArray, $upMovieArray);
```